# GAS, Update User infos : AdminSDK Directory Service

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to GAS. I am trying to understand how AdminDirectory Service works updating a user infos.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

Here is my code, what's wrong??

```
function updateUserInfos (){
  var opt = phones{
   type : "work",
   value : "999999",
   primary : true
  };
  var updates = AdminDirectory.Users.update(opt, "user@domain.com")
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: A description of the error you're getting would be useful, and confirmation that you've definitely turned on the access to the Admin directory as per: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced ?

Comment: No error, simply no changes anymore. Access are turned on... Confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function updateUserInfos (){
  var opt = {"phones":[{
     "type" : "work",
     "value" : "999999",
     primary : true
    }]
  };
  var updates = AdminDirectory.Users.update(opt, "user@domain.com")
}
```

if multiple phones

```
var opt = {"phones":[{"type" : "work",
     "value" : "999999",
     primary : true}],
    [{"type" : "mobile",
     "value" : "88888" }]
  };
```

Stéphane

Comment: You could said what you changed and why.

Comment: Sorry I replied quickly because I had to leave. Just changed the structure of opt var. it was not a valid json format. Just compare the 2 lines.

Comment: Thank you St3ph ... it works! I was just confused about sintax.